# How to implement Drag & Drop in ListRow in Leanback Library

Tags: android, android-tv

- I am developing Android TV Launcher app using Leanback Library,
- I want to perform reorder list item in this project,
- I want to perform reorder on Listrow item,
- I want to reorder games list (see attached image)
- I am doing R&D from last few days but i didnt get any solution,
- My project stuck here,
- If anyone know solution for this, please share your knowledge.

Thanks[image]